# Finite dimensional representations of semi-simple Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I've been trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

An injective map of $\mathfrak{g}$-representations of a semisimple Lie algebra splits.

I'm supposed to show this considering the $\mathfrak{g}$-representations $S= \lbrace \phi \in \text{Hom}(V,U) : \phi \text{ is a scalar on } U \rbrace$ and $T=\lbrace \phi \in \text{Hom}(V,U) : \phi(U)=0 \rbrace$. Supposedly, we consider the quotient $T/S$, but this doesn't make any sense to me - surely $T \subset S$? Then, theoretically, $T/S$ is a trivial representation, and this is in the subspace of invariants $T/S^{\mathfrak{g}}$, and so as the map $T \rightarrow T/S$ is surjective and a map of $\mathfrak{g}$-representations, then there is (by properties of the Casimir operator) a $t \in T$ mapping to this. Then, does this mean $t \circ i$ then is scalar multiplication on $U$. I'm very confused.

Any help would be appreicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Weyl's theorem, every finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-module of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, i.e., every submodule of it has a complement. Hence all extensions of modules are trivial, i.e.,
$$
0=ext(B,A)=H^1(\mathfrak{g},Hom(B,A)).
$$
In other words, every short exact sequence of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow C\rightarrow B\rightarrow 0$ splits (here the map $A\rightarrow C$ is injective).

Comment: I haven't covered any homological algebra  before, so I'm not really following the above argument. Is there anyway of showing this in a different way?

Comment: "Splitting" for semisimple Lie algebras is always involving Weyl's theorem. You can prove it with the Casimir operator, which you have mentioned. So you do not really need homological algebra.

Comment: I don't really understand how to prove it for an injective map using the Casimir operator, I'm trying to figure that out. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: See [here](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/weyls-theorem-on-complete-reducibility/) for a proof.